# Stop sound alerts for import screenshot called from bash

Tags: command-line, bash, sound

I'm running a loop to capture my desktop every minute in order to create a time-lapse movie.

The command is simply:

```bash
while true; do d=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"`; import -window root ${d}.png; sleep 1m; done
```

The annoying thing is that the default alert "beep" sounds every time it fires.  I've changed the settings in the terminal to untick "Terminal bell", but I still get the sound.  I don't want to disable sound completely, or even to cancel all alerts, I just want this job (or its hosting terminal) to be literally quiet.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS and GNOME 42.5.

Comment: `while true; do d=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"); import -silent -window root ${d}.png; sleep 1m; done`

Comment: Perfect answer for my specific situation, I guess I was asking the question too generally.  Thank you @Raffa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man import`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/import.im6.1.html):

> **-silent**              operate silently, i.e. don't ring any bells

So you can use the `-silent` option like so:

```bash
while true; do d=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M"); import -silent -window root ${d}.png; sleep 1m; done
```

Please also notice that back-ticks for command substitution are deprecated in favor of `$(...)` in bash.